# Floating Action Button problems

Tags: android, maps, new-operator, floating-action-button

I'm trying to make a FAB launch another activity in my Application. It'll open the Maps API.
I'm new at this an keep getting errors or my app crashes.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_maps"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:onClick="activity_maps"/>
```

And I also can't seem to figure out how to make the Maps activity open the map. It shows the Google Icon in the bottom corner but that's all I get.

Thanks!

Comment: put your error under question!!!

Comment: The code you included is not where your problem lies. We need code for the `Activity` containing the map, and we need a stack trace indicating where the crash occurred.

Comment: Post where you are getting an issue, post the stacktrace if there is a crash, post the `activity_maps` method, etc. Don't just post a layout snippet if your issue is programmatic.

Comment: I found a way around this by switching to a standard button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.